# Separate the content intside a tag from the content outside

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say I have this XML file:

```
<paragraph>
  Hello <bold>World</bold>!
</paragraph>
```

and I would like to get separately the content inside the `<bold>` tag (i.e. `World`) from the content outside it (i.e. `Hello` and `!`). Or I rather would like to transform this XML with XSL like this:

```
<p>
  Hello <b>World</b>!
</p>
```

How should I do?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <b>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </b>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```